# Customize chem-angew biblatex style

Tags: biblatex

My university is not happy with the default chem-angew style. It should look like this:

Book Chapter Reference: author(s), title, In: *book title*, Ed.: Editor(s), publisher, **(year)**, volume, page from-to

My MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew, articletitle=true, chaptertitle=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibparens{#1}}} % <- does not work

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}

@inbook{ullmannPolyacrylates,
author = {Penzel, Erich and Ballard, Nicholas and Asua, José M.},
publisher = {Wiley},
editor = {{Elvers B. Wiley-VCH Verlag GmbH and Co. KGaA}},
title = {Polyacrylates},
booktitle = {Ullmann's Encyclopedia of Industrial Chemistry},
pages = {1-20},
year = {2018},
volume = {40}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  In \cite{ullmannPolyacrylates} one can see stuff

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

I need to change

- There should be a comma after the title of the chapter (.., Polyacrylates, ...)
- "in" has to be changed to In: (..., In: ...)
- The **year** has to be changed to **(year)**
- No parentheses around the editors
- Only the number of the volume after the year (**(2018)**, 40, ...)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Note that what is given here as the `editor` looks suspiciously like the `publisher`. So maybe you want to change `publisher = {Wiley}, editor = {{Elvers B. Wiley-VCH Verlag GmbH and Co. KGaA}},` to just `publisher = {Wiley-VCH},`. I'd also be inclined to use the entry type `@inreference` or `@incollection` here (with the standard styles and I assume most other styles `@inreference` is an alias of `@incollection`). `@inbook` is normally used for chapters of a `@book` and a `@book` was written in its entirety by the same set of authors (who are usually jointly responsible for the complete work)

Comment: This is just me being annoying, but it would surprise me if an article about something starting with "P" were to appear in the last volume of the reference work. According to my University library, volume 40 is the index volume. In the 7th edition *Polyacrylates* would probably be in volume 28. The `pages` number also looks suspicious. If you got the entry from the online version (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/14356007.a21_157.pub2), I would drop both the `pages` and the `volume` field and would just give the DOI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the insightful comments by moewe I  change my answer because the former one, while gave a faithful response to the MWE, the reference provided was artificially (and wrongly)  made so .. GIGO.

Now I address the all requests presented.  " In: "; "**(year)**"; " Eds: ". See for example ref [8] or [12].

The comma after the title and the journal number after the year are already  defaults of the style.

I verified the result using `biblatex-examples.bib` provided by the `biblatex` installation, with a variety of references types.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=chem-angew,
articletitle=true,
chaptertitle=true
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{\printtext[date]{\printtext[parens]{\printdate}}} % added parentheses to date field

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    in       =\addcomma\addspace In\addcolon    % comma + upper case In: 
}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {%
%       \printtext[parens] % no parentheses in editor
        {%
            \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
            \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
            \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
            \clearname{editor}%
            \newunit
        }%
    }%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{enumerate}
    
\item article\cite{aksin}

\item article\cite{baez/article}

\item article\cite{bertram}

\item article\cite{kastenholz}

\item book\cite{aristotle:physics}

\item book\cite{companion}

\item mvbook\cite{aristotle:rhetoric}

\item inbook\cite{nietzsche:historie}

\item collection\cite{matuz:doody}

\item collection\cite{westfahl:frontier}

\item mvcollection\cite{britannica}

\item incollection\cite{westfahl:space}

\item incollection\cite{hyman}

\item incollection\cite{brandt}

\item InCollection\cite{gaonkar:in}
    
\item mvcollection\cite{jaffe}  
    
\item inproceedings\cite{salam}
    
\item manual\cite{cms}
    
\item online\cite{itzhaki}
    
\item patent\cite{almendro} 
    
\item report\cite{chiu}
    
\item report\cite{padhye}
    
\item thesis\cite{geer}

\end{enumerate}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Before

[image: before]

After

[image: after]

Interesting enough a new issue (not related with  the question) manifest itself with the managing of the field `commentator`. See the unnecessary dot after "comment". The same happens at least, with variants, with `style=ieee` and `style=nature`.

[image]

Comment: "with a comment. by" is a (possibly slightly infelicitous) abbreviation of "with a commentary by".

Comment: Thank you. I wouldn't have guessed. "with a comment by" is a proper construction. At least with `translator` you get only  "trans. by"

Comment: @moewe Following the same topic. See what happens with `style=nature` : no space before the "with".

Comment: Yeah, that is probably a deficiency in `biblatex-nature`, though I'm guessing that the Nature citation/reference guidelines have nothing to say about a case like this, so this probably wasn't tested. You can report this at https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-nature/issues

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't quite answer the question, but since my comments got too long, I figured I might show what I would do.

First of all I would clean up the bibliography entry in question a bit. As mentioned in the comments the `editor`, `volume` and `pages` fields all looks suspicious. Furthermore, I would use the entry type `@inreference`. And if you used the online version, I'd just give the DOI. We then have a tiny bit of work to do to convince `chem-angew` to print the DOI.

The requirements listed in the question would make the entry look more like an `@article`, which I believe is not the best fit. So I did not go into modifiyng the year and volume display as shown in the question (plus, I don't have a `volume` any more anyway).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=chem-angew,
  articletitle=true, chaptertitle=true,
  doi=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inreference,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space\bibsentence}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \ifboolexpr{    test {\iffieldundef{chapter}}
              and test {\iffieldundef{eid}}
              and test {\iffieldundef{pages}}}
    {}
    {\clearfield{doi}}%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {}
    {\clearfield{doi}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inreference{ullmannPolyacrylates,
  author    = {Penzel, Erich and Ballard, Nicholas and Asua, José M.},
  title     = {Polyacrylates},
  year      = {2018},
  maintitle = {Ullmann's Encyclopedia of Industrial Chemistry},
  publisher = {Wiley-VCH},
  doi       = {10.1002/14356007.a21_157.pub2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  In \cite{ullmannPolyacrylates} one can see stuff

  \autocite{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: E. Penzel, N. Ballard, J. M. Asua, Polyacrylates, In: Ullmann’s Encyclopedia of Industrial Chemistry, Wiley-VCH, 2018, DOI 10.1002/14356007.a21_157.pub2.]