# changing the angew style file to include only URLs?

Tags: bibtex, bst

I am currently using the angew file to include the references.

I would like to change it (or even use a different style file) on overleaf, so that the only thing that is listed in the references is the doi link with a hyperref for the doi.

Is that possible?

This is related, but not helpful, because it doesn't remove the rest of the information, I believe (I only want the link to be listed):

[Bibtex: adjust bst to include doi as link only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666659/bibtex-adjust-bst-to-include-doi-as-link-only)

Here is the angew.bst file:

https://www.sys.kth.se/docs/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/rsc/angew.bst

(I am not committed to angew, what I like about it is that it shows the references as footnote numbers next to the \cite command.)

Comment: You have tagged this question with `bibtex`, `bst` and `biblatex`. `biblatex` is incompatible with `.bst` styles used by BibTeX. So are you looking for a `biblatex` or BibTeX/`bst` solution?

Comment: `angew` does not appear to be a LaTeX package that's distributed with TeXLive. Is `angew.sty` available online? If so, where? Or are you maybe referring to the `chem-angew` biblatex package that's mentioned at [this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575232/5001)? Please clarify.

Comment: thank you, I edited my question.

Comment: there is still no example that anyone can use to test. the final comment "I am not committed to angew, what I like about it is that it shows the references as footnote numbers next to the \cite command" seems odd, a bst file has no effect on the formatting of `\cite` if citations are appearing as footnotes that is due to code you have not shown.